# Test of remote REST service API specifically HubSpot

Tags: rest, spring-boot, service, integration-testing

I intend to write a Spring Boot application which internally works on some contact/custmer data and I want to integrate HubSpot. For instance I have a contact ID which I want to use to request the HubSpot API (update, delete, get profile, ...).

What is the best way to write integration tests for HubSpot?

1. Should I do at all?
2. I expect a JSON response when I ask HubSpot to get a profile, or, if I update a contact. How should I test this?
3. Should I test that I get some JSON, or, should I test the structure of the JSON maybe to get some more information of that contact to continue some workflow?
4. Or, should I write just unit tests for my service which in fact requests the HubSpot API?

Answer (score 1):

This is an interesting question. Many questions around the what should I test get the quick answer of well it depends, essentially on the risk you are prepared to take. Here is a [blog post](https://www.diffblue.com/blog/2019/8/1/should-i-write-automated-tests-for-my-code) I wrote on the subject for background.

In terms of the technicality of testing a HubSpot integration. HubSpot have [documentation](https://developers.hubspot.com/docs/faq/how-do-i-create-a-test-account) that tells you how to create test users that can be used to test your integration.

Now, onto the what tests should you write?

First of all, `Should I do it at all?`, in my opinion the answer is yes. Simply you have two moving parts, your code and HubSpot as a service. Either one could change and break your integration. Without suitable tests it will become harder to debug when it happens.

Now onto the how to test. There are three types of test that will help here:

1. Unit testing. This would be testing the code that you have written. In this case I would mock the response from HubSpot so that you are testing the code but not actually call HubSpot.
2. Integration testing. I assume the basis of your question given the tags. For this I would use a test account and check each of the behaviours that you expect.

   - Create a user
   - Update a user etc.

Using a test account you can do this in a controlled manner. Where the only moving parts are your calls to the HubSpot API and their responses. This will easily highlight issues as you modify your code, or, as HubSpot ship new releases. This is the level that will give you confidence that your integration is correct. At this point I would verify the response, structure and value from HubSpot. Also, I would check that the correct action (in the case of create or update a user) has been performed.

3. End to end testing. Complete flow through your Spring boot application using a test user on HubSpot. This will of course give you confidence that your entire application is behaving. However, if there is a failure here caused by the integration with HubSpot you would hope for a corresponding integration test failure to help with the debugging.